# Копирование каталога на несколько серверов

Tags: linux, bash

Я хочу скопировать каталог /home/backup на сервера samba nt video, но подобный скрипт не работает:

```
#!/bin/sh
servers="samba nt video"
src=/home/backup
for srv in $servers ; do
  rsync -a $src $srv:$src
done
```

Comment: Этим скриптом я хочу скопировать каталог /home/backup на сервера samba nt video

Comment: Пользуйтесь возможностью редактирования вопроса вместо добавления важной информации в комментариях к нему

Answer (score 1):

Вот так работает?

```
$ rsync -a user@server:/home/backup/ /home/backup
```

Тогда добаьте `-vx` для отладки и посмотрите что получилось:

```
#!/bin/sh -vx
...
```

Comment: Да,работает.

Comment: Добаьте -vx для отладки и посмотрите что получилось #!/bin/sh -vx

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/shservers="samba nt video"src='/home/backup'for srv in $servers ; do    rsync -a $src username@$srv:$srcdone
```